# Azure VM data disks from cold storage

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

I am running two VM's on Azure, on one I can add data disks from cold storage but on the other I cannot, despite the cold storage being in the same resource group.

Specs:
VM1:
OS: Windows (Windows Server Datacenter)
Size: Standard DS11 v2 (2 vcpus, 14 GiB memory)
[Image of disk adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qsrzc.png)

VM2:
OS: Windows10
Size: Standard B2s (2 vcpus, 4 GiB memory)
[Image of disk adding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef0n8.png)

When adding a disk to VM1 from its RG cold storage it works perfectly, however on VM2 when clicking add data disk i cannot even choose the cold storage.
The adding buttons are also different not sure if this has something to do with it.

If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi So for everyone you were wondering about this it has to do with Managed disk.
On the creation of the VM if you select the managed disk you will be limited to only select disk in azure, so if you want to add a pre-existing disk you need to create an azure disk in your resource group and then you can add it like that.